# Capturing Return Code from R in SAS IML

Tags: r, sas, sas-iml

I have a `submit /r;` block in IML.  95% of the time, things run correctly.  The other times there is an ERROR in R.

My log shows

```
ERROR: R: <whatever the error message is>
```

When an error occurs, the outputs are not available.  Is there a way to trap or detect the first error so I do not attempt to pull outputs that don't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ok` option in `submit` statement ([ref](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/63541/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_procs_sect006.htm)).  Later in the code, you can handle the error based on the value of the variable that stores the information from `ok`.

```
submit / R ok = isOK;
  * Do stuff;
endsubmit;

if isOK then do;
  * Handle the no error case;
end;
else
  * handle the error case;
```

It does not appear that you can capture the error message itself, unless you write the R script to return some error code instead of failing.

Comment: Does not seem to work.  I get an error and isOK = 0.  Perhaps the R function I am using is not setting an error code.

Comment: Can you refactor the R code to throw and catch errors?

Comment: Yup, already moving that direction.  Actually not my R code, but I have enough to do it.  Thanks for the insight.